# Functional derivative of function with respect to its derivative

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations

If $u: \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ then what is the following solution to:
$$
\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial \nabla u} = \hspace{2mm} ?
$$

Where $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial \nabla u}$ is the derivative of a scalar with respect to a vector.

**Edit**

The first version of the question did not really make much sense. I guess what I meant to say was, what is 
$$
\dfrac{df}{df'} = \hspace{5mm} ?
$$
in an attempt to solve the next problem.
I have since updated the question to fit the definitions.

Comment: How do you define these expressions?

Comment: @gerw I noticed that my first question does not really make sense. The second expression $\partial u/ \partial \nabla u$, however, is defined as the _derivative of a scalar with respect to a vector_.

Comment: I have updated the question with the proper definitions.

Comment: What possible purpose doa striking out text serves? If the text useful, keep it — if it is not, delete it.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez as you wish

Comment: The question still does not make sense. The notation $\partial f / \partial x$ usually denotes the *partial derivative* of $f$ w.r.t. $x$. For this, $x$ has to be an argument of $f$.

Comment: Please take a look at the section "Determining functional derivatives" where this notation is employed so we make sure we are on the same page. Although if I understand correctly what you are saying then $u$ would have to depend on $u'$ to make sense?
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative#Determining_functional_derivatives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $x$ and let $\gamma(x)$ be some path from $0$ to $x$. Then $f(x) = \int_{\gamma(x)} \nabla f \cdot dr.$ The functional derivative of this w.r.t. $\nabla f$ is defined as the linear functional (often a distribution) $\delta u$ given by
$$\langle u, \phi \rangle = \left. \frac{d}{d\lambda} \int_{\gamma(x)} \nabla (f+\lambda\phi) \cdot dr \right|_{\lambda=0}$$
Now, the right hand side equals
$$\left. \int_{\gamma(x)} \frac{\partial}{\partial\lambda} \nabla (f+\lambda\phi) \cdot dr \right|_{\lambda=0}
= \left. \int_{\gamma(x)} \nabla \phi \cdot dr \right|_{\lambda=0}
= \int_{\gamma(x)} \nabla \phi \cdot dr
$$
Thus,
$$\langle u, \phi \rangle = \int_{\gamma(x)} \nabla \phi \cdot dr
= \phi(x) - \phi(0) = \langle \delta(t-x) - \delta(t), \phi(t) \rangle$$
so the functional derivative is
$$\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial \nabla f(t)} = \delta(t-x) - \delta(t)$$
Luckily this result doesn't depend on the choice of $\gamma(x).$

Comment: Thank you! This is perfect. One small question though, if the domain of integration is fixed (ie. does not depend on $x$) then what would happen? Would the functional derivative equal 1? I'm sorry if this doesn't make sense, but I'm not far into the study of functionals.

Comment: @CarlosBrito. I'm not sure I get your question, but notice that I never vary $x$, it's kept fixed.